# How do I unlock Gold Mario in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

I've read conflicting information so I'm looking for the truth on what is required to unlock Gold Mario in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe for Nintendo Switch.

Most of what I read simply says you need to finish first in every race on 200cc. Does that mean complete each cup winning the gold? Or Do you have to win each cup with a gold and 3 stars (AKA a perfect 60 points). Also, do you also need to have the same completed for 50cc, 100cc, 150cc, and mirror modes?

FYI here is a quick note on how to unlock the other gold items:

- **Gold Glider:** Collect 5,000 coins in total. (See your stats screen for current total)
- **Gold Standard Kart:**  Win every Cup with at least a single star on 50cc, 100cc, 150cc and Mirror Mode in Grand Prix.
- **Gold Tires:**  Beat every Staff Ghost in Time Trial mode at 150cc. There's one for every track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get Gold Mario, you need to drive all 200cc cups in Gold.

I am sure that you do not need to get any stars. Get all gold trophies, and that's it. But you will have a hard time trying to get them. Good Luck!

Comment: I’ve suggested a modification to your answer that includes screen captures as proof of your answer. I’ll mark it as the answer once you include those photos.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Here you go [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klguNWIGOxA).

Answer (score 3):

To get Gold Mario, you need to get a gold trophy in every 200cc cup. No stars, and no need to get first in every single race, as long as you get a gold trophy.

Answer (score -1):

Complete each 200cc races. No need to get stars, just as long as you get a gold trophy for each and every race.
Also for the Gold Glider, you need to get at least 5,000 coins overall in the game.
The Gold Wheels require that you beat every staff ghost on the 150cc tracks, and be aware that there is one for each and every track. 
Finally to get the Gold Kart, get at least one star [55 - 60 points] for every 150cc and 150cc Mirror cup. That basically requires that you get 1st 3/4 of the races. Then you can come either 1st, 2nd, or 3rd in the last race or basically whichever race you want to in the cup.
Thanks!